# ImportError: No module named 'image'

Tags: linux, python-3.x

I am working on a faceRecognizer code written with python 3. I am getting this error :

```
import image ImportError: No module named 'image'
```

how can I import this  module ?

Answer (score 4):

Install: `pip install pillow`   More details from [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow/3.2.0).

and Try this: `from PIL import Image`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
>>> import Image
>>>
```

Make sure you have installed the dependencies by doing a

```
$ sudo apt-get install tesseract && pip install pytesseract
```

Comment: this went well!
yet I had an other error in a module named " numpy" that I didn't understand its utility.
"   import numpy as np
ImportError: No module named 'numpy' "

Comment: Did you do `$ sudo apt-get install python-numpy` yet?
Please click green tick to accept my answer if it solved your question.